# Single DBDataRecord From DataReader

Tags: c#, datareader

I am using the following generic data helper function to run queries and return them as a collection of DbDataRecords.

```
public static IEnumerable<DbDataRecord> GetDataRecords(string Query, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters, CommandType CommandType = CommandType.Text)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection Connection = CreateConnection())
        {   
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, Connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType;

                foreach (var Parameter in Parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Parameter.Key, Parameter.Value);
                }

                Connection.Open();     
                using (MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    foreach (DbDataRecord record in Reader)
                    {
                        yield return record;
                    }          
                }                    
                Connection.Close();  
            }
        } 
    }
```

This works great for multiple results, but I'd also like to create a function that returns a single record from the reader as a single DbDataRecord. What I cant figure out is how to convert a single row from a reader into a  DbDataRecord. Here is what I have so far:

```
 public static DbDataRecord GetDataRecord(string Query, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters, CommandType CommandType = CommandType.Text)
    {
        DbDataRecord Record = null;

        using (MySqlConnection Connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, Connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType;

                foreach (var Parameter in Parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Parameter.Key, Parameter.Value);
                }

                Connection.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                   if(Reader.Read() != false)                        
                   {
                       Record = ???;
                   }                        
                }
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return Record;
    }
```

I have seen lots of examples that show how to return one column (ExecuteScalar), that is not what I am looking for. I also know how to get individual column values. Again, that is not what I am looking to do.

Basically I want to be replace the following foreach loop

```
foreach (DbDataRecord record in Reader)
{
    yield return record;
}
```

with something that converts a single reader row into a DBDataRecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `IDataRecord` instead, that could be sufficient, then you can return the `MySqlDataReader` directly. Or you have to cast it accordingly:

So this is not possible directly:

```
Record = (DbDataRecord)Reader;
```

but in this way:

```
Record = (DbDataRecord)(IDataRecord)Reader;
```

Comment: I ended up using your suggestion to return IDataRecord instead of DbDataRecord. One issue I ran into was that I had to remove the using statement from MySqlConnection Connection = CreateConnection() and MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(). I understand that the reader is destroyed once I exit the using statement, but since I have assigned the reader's output to an IDataRecord I thought that would keep it alive. My whole point in returning an IDataRecord or DBDataRecord was because they remain alive after the connection is closed.

Comment: @LouiseEggleton: I would suggest to create a custom class that, create an instance in the method and return that instead. That's much more meaningful and maintainable (but also more work). If you need a generic in-memory object you could return a `DataRow` instead. However, i would always close/dispose a `DataReader`/`Command`/`Connection` as soon as possible best with the `using`-statement.

Comment: Tim, it is my intention to put this in a class as well as some other DB methods. At this point I was just trying to get my generic Query methods to work so I hadn't got that far. I am using Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection) to close the connection, but I still don't understand why if I assign the Reader output to an IDataRecord variable, why the IDataRecord variable is destroyed when the using statement is exited.

Comment: @LouiseEggleton: because by leaving the method via `return` you're leaving the `using`-statement which calls `reader.Dispose`(the `IDataRecord` is still the reader just casted). That makes sense since a `DataReader` is not an in-memory object but one that requires an open database connection to retrieve the records and fields. Note that a `DataReader` is not a `DataTable` where all is already loaded, its an unbuffered stream to the db.